# EXCEL Formula to find a value and return column it is found in

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have some data organized similar to the below:

```
Week 1      Week 2      Week 3
HCE738886   HCE737035   HCE737742 
HCE736755   HCE738587   HCE737823 
HCE738711   HCE737139   HCE736870
```

The data would start in Cell A1.

I want to be able to find out which column the value `HCE737139` appears in.

In my actual data set there are 100s of columns and 1000s of Rows, and I will need to find more than one value.

Is there a formula that can do this, something like a 2 step `MATCH` ?

I have tried using `MATCH` but can only make this work to find the exact position within a single column or row.

Ideally I would like to avoid any macros for this, as the look up values may at time be on a different sheet, and sometime different workbook, so any UDFs may not work in these instances.

I'm hoping some type of array can do the trick.

Comment: You say you need to find more than one value. That means you will use the formula multiple times or that each value appears more than once and you need all of them?

Comment: @Moacir the value I want to look for will be in a list in another column

Comment: Could you expand the example a bit? I think my solution might work, but I am unsure

Comment: basically I will swap `HCE737139` for Cell reference i.e =`SUMPRODUCT(--(A1:C3="EH2")*COLUMN(A1:C3))` thanks again !!!

Comment: Happy to help :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering your range is `A1:C3`:

For the complete address of the cell, you can use `=ADDRESS(SUMPRODUCT(--(A1:C3="HCE737139")*ROW(A1:C3)),SUMPRODUCT(--(A1:C3="HCE737139")*COLUMN(A1:C3)))`

For only the column number, `SUMPRODUCT(--(A1:C3="HCE737139")*COLUMN(A1:C3))`

For the actual column letter, `=SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1,SUMPRODUCT(--(A1:C3="HCE737139")*COLUMN(A1:C3)),4),1,)`

While `SUMPRODUCT`here is working as an array, this is not an array formula, so no need for `CTRL+ENTER`

Comment: This is PERFECT, it even works across 2 workbooks !